# MySQL query optimization for large data set @ 400K rows +

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query, and its main purpose is to create a view

```
SELECT block.id,min(block.timestamp)timestamp, historic.usd 
FROM block, historic 
WHERE block.timestamp <= historic.timestamp
GROUP BY id;
```

To query these tables

`block` table:

```
| ID | timestamp              |
|  0 |  2013-08-22 00:38:05   |
|  1 |  2013-08-22 00:37:53   |
```

`historic` table:

```
| timestamp             | USD |
|  2013-08-22 00:37:53  | 800 |
|  2013-08-22 00:38:30  | 799 |
|  2013-08-22 00:40:53  | 789 |
```

It does the job fine on really small data set, but my data set is over 400k rows.  How can i optimize it?  i do realize i need to use join some where to speed it.

sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d54afc/8

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to get per block id? Please add expected result

Comment: Query does not make sense. min(block.timestamp) just returns the timestamp from block table (there is only one per block id, so no use for the MIN function). The usd value you will get in this case is a random usd from any of the historic records that have a newer timestamp...

Comment: Galz is right. I think the historic table should also have block_id FK to the block table

Comment: the historic table are the data that i crawled, i did not pre-compute the data set to match its respective block_id

Answer (score 0):

If i understand better, you want for each block the current USD price, so

Try this:

```
SELECT b.*,
    (SELECT h.usd
    FROM historic h
    WHERE h.timestamp <= b.timestamp
    AND NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 'NEXT' FROM historic h2
      where h2.timestamp > h.timestamp
      and h2.timestamp <= b.timestamp)
    )
FROM block b
```

This query returns for your data set, always 800 USD. But I don't know if you want that. Please add your expect result

My [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d54afc/9/0)

**EDIT** to answer Neels comment:

Dear, this is the screenshot, but my query taken 4 ms instead of 13 ms[image]

Comment: Subqueries take longer. Isn't it? If you compare the time taken by your query and clinraus's query then you can see the difference. Check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d54afc/13

Comment: Just tried it, it did work better then the previous query i had.  But it took **19mins** to query the data by joining with my other query.  I did verify the other set of query that im using by only joining the `block` table with the other set of query i had it - that took 2ms.

Comment: @clinraus: Have you tried to add index on your tables? Which is the primary key of historic table?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is a simple modification of the query using `JOIN`.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT block.id,min(block.timestamp)timestamp, historic.usd 
FROM block
JOIN historic 
ON block.timestamp <= historic.timestamp
GROUP BY id;
```

Here is the working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d54afc/11).

Comment: And how is this different to the original statement in the question? You only replaced the old outdated implicit joins with an *explicit* `JOIN` - but the join is still the same.

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name , I think the join in the question is cross join whereas what Neels has done is INNER join, is it not correct?

Comment: Personally I prefer the join syntax as its makes it clearer that the tables are joined and how they are joined. In case the query was a larger one it would become difficult to understand what is being joined and what is it to be filtered on. In both cases however the exec plans will be the same, but the user can get a better idea on optimization if the query structure is more clear.

Comment: @Neels Explicit joins are indeed better practice and more readable, but will not improve query run time..

Answer (score 0):

You might try to add an index for the field `timestamp` in both tables (perhaps a composite key in the first case): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed89c/1